# show two components in vuejs, but only one got displayed, why?

Tags: vue.js

vuejs newbie got a question, I created two components, 'hello' and 'world', when display then two in the html, only one got displayed, why? Thanks,

https://jsfiddle.net/aaoehLqe/3/

```
<div id="app">
    <hello :msg="'test1'" /> 
    <world :msg="'test2'" />     
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Self closing tags](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036) are not a valid syntax. Try

```
<hello :msg="'test1'></hello>
<world :msg="'test2'></world>
```